# Passar values dos checkboxes para um elemento contido em uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery

O exemplo abaixo funciona da seguinte forma:

Ao fornecer todos os dados (nome, telefone, status e marcar pelo menos um checbox, um button é carregado dentro da `<div id="btnSubmit"></div>`.

Consigo recuperar o nome (em tempo real) e inserir nessa div.

A dificuldade: Não estou conseguindo carregar para essa div os valores dos checkboxes checados. Tentei usar uma função `showSelectedValues()` mas não surtiu efeito.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function showSelectedValues()
{
selecionados =($("input[name=numero]:checked").map(
function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
}

$('form').validate({
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

    var formSelector = '#' + this.currentForm.id;
    var formObject = $(formSelector);
    var validateObject = formObject.validate();
    var numberOfInvalids = validateObject.numberOfInvalids();
      
    showSelectedValues();

    if(numberOfInvalids == 0)
      $("#btnSubmit").html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"><span class="reservar">Clique aqui para reservar rifa para <span style="color:black;"> '+$("#nome").val()+'</span></span>'+selecionados+'</button>');
    else
      $("#btnSubmit").html('');
          
  }
});
    
$("#form1").valid();
  
});
```

```css
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/340517/wamp-mensagem-de-warning#
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="http://kithomepage.com/inga/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="pai" class="pai">

<form action="#" class="cmxform" id="form1">
<table class="table table-responsive"><tr><td colspan="10">

<span class="titulo2">Digite o nome, telefone, status (pago, deve etc..) e marque pelo menos um n&uacute;mero!</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="10">

<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="nome" required>
</div>
<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="telefone" required>
</div>
<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="status" name="status" placeholder="Pago / Deve" required>
</div><br><br>
  
<div id="btnSubmit"></div>
  
</td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="01" name="numero[]" required> 01</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="02" name="numero[]" required> 02</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="03" name="numero[]" required> 03</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="04" name="numero[]" required> 04</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="05" name="numero[]" required> 05</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="06" name="numero[]" required> 06</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="07" name="numero[]" required> 07</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="08" name="numero[]" required> 08</td></tr></table></form></div></td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: Essa variável "global" `selecionados` vc vai usar em outro ponto? Meio desnecessário ela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema estava na hora de pegar o nome do campo, o nome dos seus checkboxes contém "numero" e não são apenas "numero", segue o código, testado e funcionando!

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="http://kithomepage.com/inga/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="pai" class="pai">

<form action="#" class="cmxform" id="form1">
<table class="table table-responsive"><tr><td colspan="10">

<span class="titulo2">Digite o nome, telefone, status (pago, deve etc..) e marque pelo menos um n&uacute;mero!</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="10">

<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="nome" required>
</div>
<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="telefone" required>
</div>
<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="status" name="status" placeholder="Pago / Deve" required>
</div><br><br>
  
<div id="btnSubmit"></div>
  
</td></tr><tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="01" name="numero[]" required> 01</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="02" name="numero[]" required> 02</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="03" name="numero[]" required> 03</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="04" name="numero[]" required> 04</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="05" name="numero[]" required> 05</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="06" name="numero[]" required> 06</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="07" name="numero[]" required> 07</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="08" name="numero[]" required> 08</td></tr></table></form></div></td></tr></table></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function showSelectedValues()
{
//o problema estava aqui
selecionados =($("input[name*=numero]:checked").map(
function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
}

$('form').validate({
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

  var formSelector = '#' + this.currentForm.id;
  var formObject = $(formSelector);
  var validateObject = formObject.validate();
  var numberOfInvalids = validateObject.numberOfInvalids();
      
  showSelectedValues();

  if(numberOfInvalids == 0)
    $("#btnSubmit").html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"><span class="reservar">Clique aqui para reservar rifa para <span style="color:black;"> '+$("#nome").val()+'</span></span>'+selecionados+'</button>');
  else
    $("#btnSubmit").html('');
          
  }
});
    
$("#form1").valid();
  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Rapaz, por um mero `*` (asteristico) quase jogo fora esse script que suei para elaborar!!

Comment: kkkkkk acontece. bom código para você! @LeoCaracciolo

Answer (score 0):

Se você não gosta do `*` (asteristico) pode usar o `^` (chapeuzinho conhecido como acento circunflexo)!

[atributo Starts With](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) - Seleciona elementos que possuem o atributo especificado com um valor que começa exatamente com uma determinada string `input[name^=num]`, no caso em questão, `num`, poderia ser `numero`, ou `numer` ou etc....

Seleciona elementos que possuem o atributo especificado com um valor que começa exatamente com uma determinada string, no caso em questão, quantidade.

> retirei o boostrap para melhor visualização ao executar o exemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[id^="num"]')

function showSelectedValues()
{
selecionados =($("input[name^=numero]:checked").map(
function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
}

$('form').validate({
  showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

    var formSelector = '#' + this.currentForm.id;
    var formObject = $(formSelector);
    var validateObject = formObject.validate();
    var numberOfInvalids = validateObject.numberOfInvalids();
      
    showSelectedValues();

    if(numberOfInvalids == 0)
      $("#btnSubmit").html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"><span class="reservar">Clique aqui para reservar rifa para <span style="color:black;"> '+$("#nome").val()+'</span></span> '+selecionados+'</button>');
    else
      $("#btnSubmit").html('');
          
  }
});
    
$("#form1").valid();
  
});
```

```html
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kithomepage.com/inga/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="pai" class="pai">

<form action="#" class="cmxform" id="form1">
<table class="table table-responsive"><tr><td colspan="10">

<span class="titulo2">Digite o nome, telefone, status (pago, deve etc..) e marque pelo menos um n&uacute;mero!</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="10">

<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="nome" required>
</div>
<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="telefone" required>
</div>
<div class="col-1">
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="status" name="status" placeholder="Pago / Deve" required>
</div><br><br>
  
<div id="btnSubmit"></div>
</td></tr><tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="01" name="numero[]" required> 01</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="02" name="numero[]" required> 02</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="03" name="numero[]" required> 03</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="04" name="numero[]" required> 04</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="05" name="numero[]" required> 05</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="06" name="numero[]" required> 06</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="07" name="numero[]"  required> 07</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="08" name="numero[]" required> 08</td>
</tr></table></form></div></td></tr></table></div>
```